bash script expects "done" although it exists
The following script leads for the following error:
for domain in domain1 domain2 domain3; do
  int=$(yq e '.services[]' int-$domain.yaml)
  prod=$(yq e '.services[]' prod-$domain.yaml)
  missing_services=()
done

line 4: syntax error: unexpected "(" (expecting "done")
All I try to do is to initialize an empty array that I'll use later in the code.
What am I missing here?

How are you running it? Do you have a #!/bin/bash shebang line? I suspect you're running this in plain sh rather than bash. Plain sh doesn't have () array syntax.

(to expand on that: plain sh doesn't have arrays at all, except the argument list itself)

...that is to say, the expecting "done" isn't really the important part of the message, it's the "(" unexpected that tells us what's wrong.

BTW, we also know it isn't bash because that's not how bash formats its syntax errors. (It's how bash should format its syntax errors IMHO, but that's a separate matter).

Suggestion: Run it with bash. After all it is a bash script.

Syntax error aside, the loop isn't useful, because you repeatedly overwrite int, prod, and missing_services.  Work done for anything before domain3 is lost.
